# Populate from database and export array

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. I have data in my MongoDB collection. I can fetch this data. Now I'm using a template that I found online. It has a Grid component that I'm using to display all my data.

Here's how I'm fetching the data

```
const [recruitList, setRecruitList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/read").then((res) => {
    setRecruitList(res.data);
  });
}, []);
```

Now, I want to populate this variable with as many rows or objects as there are in my collection.

```
export const recruitsData = [
  {
    Degree: 10248,
    RecruitName: 'Vinet',
    RecruitEmail: 32.38,
    PhoneNumber: '51481369',
    Skills: 'USA',
    Status: 'pending',
    StatusBg: '#FB9678',
    ProductImage:
      product6,
  },
];
```

For now, I'm just passing static data like this. I want to actually populate it with the data I'm getting from MongoDB.

Here's what the localhost:8080/read gives

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62dc175ee1c7efe9fca97968"
  },
  "college_name": null,
  "company_names": [
    "Marathwada Mitra Mandal’s College of Engineering"
  ],
  "degree": [
    "B.E. IN COMPUTER ENGINEERING"
  ],
  "designation": [
    "Machine Learning",
    "Schlumberger\nDATA ENGINEER",
    "TECHNICAL CONTENT WRITER"
  ],
  "email": "omkarpathak27@gmail.com",
  "experience": [
    "Schlumberger",
    "DATA ENGINEER",
    "July 2018 - Present",
    "• Responsible for implementing and managing an end-to-end CI/CD Pipeline with custom validations for Informatica migrations which",
    "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
    "brought migration time to 1.5 hours from 9 hours without any manual intervention",
    "• Enhancing, auditing and maintaining custom data ingestion framework that ingest around 1TB of data each day to over 70 business",
    "units",
    "• Working with L3 developer team to ensure the discussed Scrum PBI’s are delivered on time for data ingestions",
    "• Planning and Executing QA and Production Release Cycle activities",
    "Truso",
    "FULL STACK DEVELOPER INTERN",
    "• Created RESTful apis",
    "• Tried my hands on Angular 5/6",
    "• Was responsible for Django backend development",
    "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
    "June 2018 - July 2018",
    "Propeluss",
    "DATA ENGINEERING INTERN",
    "• Wrote various automation scripts to scrape data from various websites.",
    "• Applied Natural Language Processing to articles scraped from the internet to extract different entities in these articles using entity",
    "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
    "October 2017 - January 2018",
    "extraction algorithms and applying Machine Learning to classify these articles.",
    "• Also applied KNN with LSA for extracting relevant tags for various startups based on their works.",
    "GeeksForGeeks",
    "TECHNICAL CONTENT WRITER",
    "• Published 4 articles for the topics such as Data Structures and Algorithms and Python",
    "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
    "July 2017 - September 2017",
    "Softtestlab Technologies",
    "WEB DEVELOPER INTERN",
    "• Was responsible for creating an internal project for the company using PHP and Laravel for testing purposes",
    "• Worked on a live project for creating closure reports using PHP and Excel"
  ],
  "mobile_number": "8087996634",
  "name": "Omkar Pathak",
  "no_of_pages": "3",
  "skills": [
    "Parser",
    "Html",
    "Css",
    "Javascript",
    "Operating systems",
    "Github",
    "Website",
    "Flask",
    "Linux",
    "System",
    "Shell",
    "Apis",
    "Reports",
    "Engineering",
    "Opencv",
    "C",
    "Writing",
    "Php",
    "Cloud",
    "Analytics",
    "Scrum",
    "Algorithms",
    "Django",
    "Windows",
    "Automation",
    "Unix",
    "Photography",
    "Content",
    "Testing",
    "C++",
    "Machine learning",
    "Mysql",
    "Auditing",
    "Python",
    "Excel",
    "Training",
    "Migration",
    "Programming",
    "Security",
    "Technical",
    "Api"
  ],
  "total_experience": "4.5",
  "__v": 0
}
```

I have many other "rows" such as this one. How do I populate my recruitData array with them. Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT: Forgot to add the Grid structure, Here it is**

```
export const ordersGrid = [
  {
    headerText: 'Image',
    template: gridOrderImage,
    textAlign: 'Center',
    width: '120',
  },
  {
    field: 'RecruitName',
    headerText: 'Name',
    width: '150',
    editType: 'dropdownedit',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },
  { field: 'RecruitEmail',
    headerText: 'Email',
    width: '150',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },
  { field: 'PhoneNumber',
    headerText: 'Phone Number',
    width: '150',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },
  {
    headerText: 'Status',
    template: gridOrderStatus,
    field: 'OrderItems',
    textAlign: 'Center',
    width: '120',
  },
  {
    field: 'Degree',
    headerText: 'Degree',
    width: '120',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },

  {
    field: 'Skills',
    headerText: 'Skills',
    width: '150',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },
];
```

Comment: when you console log the recruitList state variable what it shows ? does it give an error ?

Comment: Perhaps posting a dump of personal information onto the internet is not a good idea?

Comment: @miken32 fake information that already exists on the internet. That data doesn't correspond to anyone it's a fake generated file for testing purposes

Comment: Then you should not be using potentially valid email addresses.

Comment: @miken32 I will repeat, the email is provided in a github project for public use. The owner stated so on YT. I understand the concern but you should not assume anything either.